# Why won't qEMU display anything when launched from Android Studio?

Tags: android

I'm just getting started with AndroidStudio by walking through Google's development tutorials. The 'hello world' script compiles just fine, but I've hit a hitch on [the step of actually running it on the QEMU emulator](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html) when launched from the ide. It briefly flashes:

"Guest has not initialized the display...yet"

Before showing a fonted "Android", and no more. It gives me an option to disable mouse-grabbing, so something's clearly happening, but nothing either phone- or code- like. Is there maybe more backend configuration that AndroidStudio expects me to do on my own? Have I not crossed my t's and dotted my i's on the device manager?

More context here-since I'm running an amd machine, I downloaded an arm64 image to circumvent my need for haxm, which only runs on x86. From the device manager, its info reads:

Name: Nexus_5_API_22

CPU/ABI: ARM (arm64-v8a)

Path: C:\Users\x.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_22.avd

Target: Android M (Preview) (API level MNC)

Skin: nexus_5

SD Card: 100M

Snapshot: no

hw.lcd.density: 480

hw.dPad: no

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.camera.back: none

disk.dataPartition.size: 200M

hw.gpu.enabled: yes

runtime.network.latency: none

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.keyboard: yes

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.device.hash2: MD5:2fa0e16c8cceb7d385183284107c0c88

hw.ramSize: 1536

tag.id: default

tag.display: Default

hw.sdCard: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.mainKeys: no

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.trackBall: no

hw.device.name: Nexus 5

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

hw.battery: yes

AvdId: Nexus_5_API_22

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

hw.audioInput: yes

hw.camera.front: none

hw.gps: yes

avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5 API 22

snapshot.present: no

vm.heapSize: 64

runtime.scalefactor: auto

I've searched the qEMU and android documentation and found just a little less than the little I did on the stack, so I'm hoping it's something simple I've overlooked that most devs wouldn't need to be addressed in same. Thanks in advance for your patience with a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck getting the emulator to work in Android Studio. I had a much more satisfactory experience with genymotion:

https://www.genymotion.com/